# Get count of rows for all files in library with SQL

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, dynamic-sql

This task has two options that comes to mind:

Option 1: Straighforward approach

1. Execute `select table_name from qsys2.systables where table_schema = 'LIBRARY'`
2. For each entry of the output execute `select count(*) from LIBRARY.TABLENAME`
3. Save result and repeat step 2.

Option 2: Dynamic sql statement

1. Try to wrap [script](http://forums.sqlteam.com/t/extract-all-tables-names-and-their-rowcounts-from-sql-linked-server-tables/3567/8) result into `begin` and subsequent `execute immediate sql; end;` statement.

Unfortunately, `with` clause in this code cannot be used with `begin` and I've no idea how to rewrite entire script properly without it.

Can somebody come out with the solution which performance is better than the stated in option 1?

Desired output format:

```
╔════════════╦═══════╗
║ TABLE_NAME ║ COUNT ║
╠════════════╬═══════╣
║ a1         ║   432 ║
║ a2         ║     9 ║
║ a3         ║     0 ║
╚════════════╩═══════╝
```

---

**UPD**

Based on answer I've come to this procedure script, which is not working, however:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LIB/CNT                                          
  LANGUAGE SQL                                                    
BEGIN                                                             
    CREATE TYPE CHARARRAY AS VARCHAR(10) ARRAY[500];              
    DECLARE NAMES CHARARRAY;                                      
    DECLARE i INTEGER;                                            
    SET i = 1;                                                    
    SET names = ARRAY[SELECT table_name FROM qsys2.systables WHERE
table_schema = 'LIBRARY'];                                        
    SET numNames = CARDINALITY(names);                            
    WHILE i <= numNames                                           
        SET stmt = 'SELECT ' || names[i] || ' AS TABLE_NAME,      
COUNT(*) FROM ' || names[i];                                      
        PREPARE s1 FROM stmt;                                     
        EXECUTE s1;                                               
    END WHILE;                                                    
END;
```

[CREATE TYPE reference.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/t0053481.html)

Error message: `Token NAMES was not valid. Valid tokens: GLOBAL.`

Adding `global` before names gives `Token NAMES was not valid. Valid tokens: TEMPORARY.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to do anything, the information is already collected by the system...

```
SELECT SYSTEM_TABLE_SCHEMA, SYSTEM_TABLE_NAME
      , NUMBER_ROWS, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME 
FROM systablestat 
WHERE SYSTEM_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MYLIB';
```

For future reference, the standard catalogs have been around for awhile.
[DB2 for i catalog views](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzcatalog.htm)

Also the DB2 for i team continues to add "services" to make information available via SQL
[DB2 for i - Services](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/IBM%20i%20Technology%20Updates/page/DB2%20for%20i%20-%20Services)

Comment: Thanks, man, that's it. I've updated your answer to be more accurate(added `qsys2`, dropped redudant columns)

Comment: @im_infamous They might be redundant to you, but not the next guy.  I included them so you'd know you could see and search for the long SQL names of things.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding the topic specifies "WITH SQL", still have to suggest,  if you don't mind executing a native AS/400 command...

DSPFD FILE(LIBRARY/*ALL) TYPE(*MBRLIST) OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) FILEATR(*PF) OUTFILE(LIBRARY/TABLLIST)

...will create or replace table "TABLLIST" containing field "MLNRCD" = Current number of records (rows) for each table/member in LIBRARY, which can more easily be processed "with SQL":

"SELECT MLFILE, MLNRCD FROM LIBRARY/TABLLIST" should then yield tables and rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following script:

```
BEGIN
    CREATE TYPE namesArray AS VARCHAR(100) ARRAY[100];
    DECLARE names namesArray;
    DECLARE i INTEGER;
    SET i = 1;
    SET names = ARRAY[SELECT table_name FROM qsys2.systables WHERE table_schema = 'LIBRARY'];
    SET numNames = CARDINALITY(names);
    WHILE i <= numNames
        SET stmt = 'SELECT ' || names[i] || ' AS TABLE_NAME, COUNT(*) FROM ' || names[i];
        PREPARE s1 FROM stmt;
        EXECUTE s1;
    END WHILE;
END
```

The strategy here is to populate the `names` array with the table names from your first query.  Then, iterate over that array and dynamically execute a count query on each table.

Comment: Unfortunately, error in line 4 at `ARRAY`: `Operation only allowed for array variables.`

Comment: @im_infamous This should be working, at least inside a stored proc, from what I can see.  [Have a look here](https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/ibmdb2/w/wiki/7790.sql-pl-array-functions-array-array-agg) where `ARRAY` is being used as I have used it in my answer.

Comment: `names` need to be declared, though. I've tried `CHARARRAY` with no success. Link: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/apsg/src/tpc/db2z_arrays.html

Comment: @im_infamous I updated my answer, please try it again.

Comment: `Token NAMES was not valid. Valid tokens: GLOBAL.`